# issue while creating a python package for PyPi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi, python-packaging

i have a project and i need to upload it into Pypi, i have folder with 3 python files(**intit**.py,setup.py, myproject.py.)
**init**.py

```
from mojadateconverter70 import YourCalendarLib,jalali,hijri,gregorian
```

mojadateconerter70 is my project and ourCalendarLib,jalali,hijri,gregorian are all the classes in my file.

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="mojadateconverter70",
    version="0.0.1",
    packages= find_packages(),
    author="Mohammadali Jalili",
    description="some functions related to date, with not much accuracy"
    
)
```

i can ulpoad it to pypi and installed using pip, However, when i want to import it, vscode,pycharm and jupyter cannot find it.
i cannot find the issue, if can help me thruogh this i will be gratefull.

Comment: You need to provide more information as to what actually happens after it is installed. Has it been added to the correct `site-packages` tree? What error messages are raised when you try to run it in those environments?

Comment: Looking at the source file from you package on PyPI (https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/10/7f61b09e0a7d41e489dfe663b6d6b37306f9aa4c4c1320d113307e647c21/mojadateconverter70-0.0.2.tar.gz), the only Python file it contains is the `setup.py` file and nothing else. I think you might need to read up a bit more about creating a valid Python package, e.g., https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/.